# Using plot_date change node icon type

Tags: matplotlib

When using plot_date, how do you change some of the nodes in the set from a circle to an X?
For example all nodes are circles except the 3, 8, and 19 node, which are all Xs.

Comment: use two calls to `plot_date`.

Comment: How do I connect the nodes of x and o?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a sample dataset, since you didnt provided any.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'2014-11-15':1, '2014-11-16':2, '2014-11-17':3, '2014-11-18':5, '2014-11-19':8, '2014-11-20': 19}
df = pd.DataFrame(list(data.iteritems()), columns=['Date', 'val'])
df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y-%m-%d'))
o_list = []
x_list = []
check_list = [3,8,19]
for index in df.index:
    if df.val[index] in check_list:
        o_list.append(index)
    else:
        x_list.append(index)

df_o = df.ix[o_list]
df_x = df.ix[x_list]
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot_date(df_o.index, df_o.val, 'bo')
plt.plot_date(df_x.index, df_x.val, 'bx')
plt.show()
```